# How to get data of nested xml objects by SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<restaurants>
    <restaurant>
        <street>Street1</street>
        <title>Restaurant1</title>
        <cuisine>Belorussian</cuisine>
        <hall capacity="per.">10</hall>
        <menu>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish1</name>
                <price currency="dol.">100</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish2</name>
                <price currency="dol.">200</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish3</name>
                <price currency="dol.">300</price>
            </dish>
        </menu>
    </restaurant>
    <restaurant>
        <street>Street2</street>
        <title>Restaurant2</title>
        <cuisine>Russian</cuisine>
        <hall capacity="per.">20</hall>
        <menu>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish4</name>
                <price currency="dol.">400</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish5</name>
                <price currency="dol.">500</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish6</name>
                <price currency="dol.">600</price>
            </dish>
        </menu>
    </restaurant>
    <restaurant>
        <street>Street3</street>
        <title>Restaurant3</title>
        <cuisine>Chinese</cuisine>
        <hall capacity="per.">30</hall>
        <menu>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish7</name>
                <price currency="dol.">700</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish8</name>
                <price currency="dol.">800</price>
            </dish>
            <dish>
                <name>Dish9</name>
                <price currency="dol.">900</price>
            </dish>
        </menu>
    </restaurant>
</restaurants>
```

Here's the code of my parser:

```
package com.sitairis.lab2;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SaxParser {
    private static List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
            parser.parse(new File("restaurant.xml"), handler);

            for (Restaurant restaurant : restaurants) {
                System.out.println(restaurant.getStreet() + " " + restaurant.getTitle() + " " + restaurant.getCapacity() + " " + restaurant.getCuisine());
                for (Dish dish: restaurant.getDishes()){
                    System.out.println(dish.getTitle());
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private String street, title, cuisine, hall, name, lastElementName;

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            super.startDocument();
        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            super.endDocument();
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
            lastElementName = qName;
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
            if ((street != null && !street.isEmpty())
                    && (title != null && !title.isEmpty())
                    && (hall != null && !hall.isEmpty())
                    && (cuisine != null && !cuisine.isEmpty())
                    && (name != null && !name.isEmpty())) {
                Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
                restaurant.setStreet(street);
                restaurant.setTitle(title);
                restaurant.setCapacity(Integer.parseInt(hall));
                restaurant.setCuisine(cuisine);

                Dish dish = new Dish();
                dish.setTitle(name);
                restaurant.setDishes(List.of(dish));

                restaurants.add(restaurant);
                street = null;
                title = null;
                cuisine = null;
                hall = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            String information = new String(ch, start, length);
            information = information.replace("\n", "").trim();
            if (!information.isEmpty()) {
                if (lastElementName.equals("street")) {
                    street = information;
                }
                if (lastElementName.equals("title")) {
                    title = information;
                }
                if (lastElementName.equals("cuisine")) {
                    cuisine = information;
                }
                if (lastElementName.equals("hall")) {
                    hall = information;
                }
                if (lastElementName.equals("name")) {
                    name = information;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            super.ignorableWhitespace(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

}
```

Probably everything is ok, but I don't understand how can I get data of this part:

```
<dish>
    <name>Dish7</name>
    <price currency="dol.">700</price>
</dish>
<dish>
    <name>Dish8</name>
    <price currency="dol.">800</price>
</dish>
<dish>
    <name>Dish9</name>
    <price currency="dol.">900</price>
</dish>
```

I can get the value only of the first object, but not 2nd and third. As I understand, something should be modified in this method, but I don't understand how to handle menu closing tag. So, can u help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to easily parse complex XML. it is easier than SAX.

You just define the mapping for data you want to extract from XML

Here are mapping definitions for your XML.

```
result: 
  type: array
  path: /restaurants/restaurant
  fields:
    street: 
    title: 
    hall:
    menus:
      path: menu/dish
      type: array
      fields:
        name:
        price: long
        currency:
          xml:
            attribute: true
```

Java Code to parse XML:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create();
Object result=  dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);
// json represntation fo result
dsm.getObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, object);
```

Here is output:

```
[ {
  "street" : "Street1",
  "title" : "Restaurant1",
  "hall" : "10",
  "menus" : [ {
    "name" : "Dish1",
    "price" : 100
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish2",
    "price" : 200
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish3",
    "price" : 300
  } ]
}, {
  "street" : "Street2",
  "title" : "Restaurant2",
  "hall" : "20",
  "menus" : [ {
    "name" : "Dish4",
    "price" : 400
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish5",
    "price" : 500
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish6",
    "price" : 600
  } ]
}, {
  "street" : "Street3",
  "title" : "Restaurant3",
  "hall" : "30",
  "menus" : [ {
    "name" : "Dish7",
    "price" : 700
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish8",
    "price" : 800
  }, {
    "name" : "Dish9",
    "price" : 900
  } ]
} ]
```

If you want to directly deserialize to a POJO class it is possible with DSM

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, I know that such libraries exist but I need to do it only with SAX :(

Comment: İs there special reasons to use Sax? İs file huge?

Comment: @mfe this library is compatible with java 1.5? Do you now any library compatible Java 1.5 with?